# Bootstrap split dropdown wraps in table heading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a split Bootstrap dropdown that I am wrapping in a form and adding to a table heading.  The issue is that when you narrow the screen size the dropdown toggle element wraps.  At first I assumed it was the form wrap but I think its the table heading.

[image][image]

Here is a http://www.bootply.com/zzRJxiYy80 for an example with live code.

Thanks,

Dan

**MINOR UPDATE (More details on comments from answer)**

In my case I am using the outline buttons.  I have Ransack sort links in each button and filters in the dropdown.  The second 'Major Category' one has a slightly wider line than the rest and at this point I am making way too much of a big deal of it.  Minor stuff like that drives me nuts but I need to let it go :)

This one is at -0.45em

[image]

I played with this and settled on -0.37em

[image]

Comment: So, uh...what behaviour would be more acceptable to you? If the table heading no longer has enough space to accommodate its content on a single line, what would you prefer it do?

Comment: It should not wrap - it's suppose to be a single button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest overriding Bootstrap's use of `float:left` for keeping these `.btn` elements on the same line, and instead use `display:inline-block` for that. Then, you can use `white-space:nowrap` to prevent them from breaking to multiple lines when space becomes limited.

Most of the styles you need (`display:inline-block` and `white-space:nowrap`) are actually already defined in Bootstrap's CSS - you just need a couple more styles to use them to your advantage:

```css
.btn-group.nowrap > .btn{
    float:none;
}
.btn-group.nowrap > .btn:not(:first-child){
    margin-left: -0.4em; /* To deal with whitespace between inline-block elements */
}
```

Here's an [updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Mq6xZCDHvX) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That's perfect - I am pretty weak on my CSS skills.  I had a look at these but didn't know where to start on this.  For bonus points do you see how the dropdown menus are hidden in the responsive table element?  Any way to have that auto-expand when you open the dropdown?  This perhaps should be a separate question but i figured i would float it anyway.

Comment: @DanTappin Glad I could help out! Yeah, that probably should be another question...but hey, the solution is simple enough that you probably don't need to ask it. =P Right now, `.table-responsive` has the style `overflow-x:auto`, which causes excess content to end up hidden (but scrollable). All you have to do is change it to `overflow-x:visible`, and the dropdown won't be hidden inside the element anymore. (Not sure what side effects this may have, doesn't cause any at the moment though.)

Comment: It's works 99% except that the margin-left option seems buggy.  as you resize that margin-left will randomly make the various headers diverter lines wider or 'normal'

Comment: @DanTappin Yeah, I see what you mean. Perhaps try `margin-left: -0.45em;`? That seems to work well enough in Bootply for me. I suspect it's something to do with relative positioning and rounding of sub-pixel values, but I'm not sure what a better approach would be.

Comment: Updated the question to clarify - I think we are good now.  Thanks again!